# Is there a way to use html in an all-flash air app?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, actionscript-3, air

I'm trying to add an HTML/JavaScript page inside an Air app made fully in flash (coded in AS3, almost no timeline used). Is it possible and wise to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [mx.controls HTML](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/HTML.html) also see [Using the HTMLControl Class in Adobe AIR to parse HTML as a data source](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2007/11/09/using-the-htmlcontrol-in-adobe-air-to-parse-html-as-a-data-source/)

Hopes that helps